# Why should `response.Close()` happen after handling returned error?

Tags: go

I noticed that in the `golangci-lint` repo there's [such a static check](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/blob/4af546a7100be2b2c9db5ccb268a153570778dee/pkg/result/processors/identifier_marker.go#L53-L54):

> should check returned error before deferring response.Close

This means the following code will fail the lint check:

```golang
    res, err := db.Conn.Query(ctx, query)
    defer res.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

However, I'm confused why the rule is like this. Shouldn't we close the response even when there's an error? Thus it makes more sense to me to defer the close before handling the error.

Comment: If there is an error, `res` is not valid and can be `nil`.